# Chrome cannot load sencha touch well

Tags: google-chrome, sencha-touch

I download Sencha Touch 2.0, and want to learn from its example. But my chrome can not load it. Chrome do not show any thing, it's white actually. But Safari can load it well. Why chrome can not? 
My chrome is the lastest, and i have reinstalled it this noon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you debugging it?

I might not be correct as I'm also learning.. 
but the below is 1 possible reasons that is causing the errors.

Are you debugging it through file:// (Running as local files)? Look at your URL bar.

If it's file://.. for safari they do not impose XSS (Cross Site Scripting) for files that run locally. But for chrome they have XSS (Cross Site Scripting) for local file.

See [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy/6083677#6083677) on how to disable same origin policy.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's done. In the same directory of chrome.exe, start chrome by this: "chrome --disable-web-security", then I can run my local file. Thanks:-)

Comment: Sorry for that. I am not so familiar with Stack Overflow. I will do better and better. Thanks!